How do I version spring cache redis objects?
How do I version spring cache redis objects?  I am encountering issues between deploys when the object version changes, and no longer match the cache structure in redis.
AI assistant gives a versioning scheme but would like to hear others solutions to this.

IMHO : (1) You don't ("harmonize").  You flush the cache when the obstruct structure changes.
(2)
But if you must... then this is good reason to write your own "abstraction" over the redis-cache.  Then you can pull out the object .. with a key .. as an object.. and then map "loosely typed properties" .. to your strong object properties.    but that's alot of drama/effort.   So see #1, "you don't".

Would you mind giving more information or snippet of code?
